# How to get same label or previous td inner tag class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code like

```
<td>
    <input type='text' class='input_text' name='subject_text_".$i."[]' style ='height: 25px;'/>
</td> 
<td>
    <input type='file' id='file' class='input_file' name='subject_".$i."[]'/>
</td>
```

When I change the file I need to add the `required` property to the input text. I tried but I've not achieved it. I used the below code:

```
function input_file(){
    var file_name = $(this).val();
    if (file_name !='') {
        alert('file is selected');
        var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
        var value = $('.' + class_name).prev('td input.class');
        $('.value').prop('required',true);
    } else {
        alert('file not selected');
    }
}

$(document).on('change', '.input_file', $(this), input_file);
```

Comment: `.value`  does not appear at `html`?

Comment: actually i did not class value that why i just add this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that the syntax of your delegate event handler is incorrect; there should be no `$(this)` in that call. Secondly the DOM traversal you're using isn't quite right. The `td` is a sibling of a parent to the file input, so `prev()` alone won't work. Finally the logic you use can be shortened just by setting the property to whether or not a file is selected. Try this:

```
function input_file() {
    $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input').prop('required', $(this).val() != '');
}

$(document).on('change', '.input_file', input_file);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/hbzot1pd/)

Comment: thanks @rory its work for me and my delegate syntax work no need to remove $(this)

Comment: It works, but you're passing `$(this)` in the `data` parameter, which you don't need to do. It's just creating a jQuery object for no reason at all. Either way, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

find selector will not work inside prev selector argument. Here is what you need to do:

1) You need to first traverse to parent td. by using `.closest('td')` or `.parent()`

2) then to its previous sibling td . using `.prev()`

3) and then find required input element in it. using `.find('input.class')`:

```
function input_file(){
 var file_name =$(this).val();
 var inputclass =$(this)closest('td').prev('td').find(' input.class');
 if(file_name !=''){
      alert('file is selected');
      // code for file selected condition
      inputclass.prop('required',true);
  }else{
      alert('file not selected');
      // code for file not selected condition
      inputclass.prop('required',false);
  }
 }
```